# How to clip text to not overflow the below component on CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my current work:

[image]

```css
.sec {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px;">
  <div class="sec">
    Big textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig text Big text Big textBig textBig textBig textBig text text Big textBig textBig textBig text Big textBig textBig textBig Big textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig text
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: black;">
</div>
```

I want that the red text clips before overflow the black div and ends with '...'. How I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try update your css with below code

```
.sec {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;               /* Newly added */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;        /* Newly added */
  display: -webkit-box;           /* Newly added */
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;          /* Newly added */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;   /* Newly added */
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: The number lines can't be static.

Answer (score 0):

You just do overflow: hidden on the your parent element:

```css
.sec {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; overflow:hidden">
  <div class="sec">
    Big textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig text Big text Big textBig textBig textBig textBig text text Big textBig textBig textBig text Big textBig textBig textBig Big textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig textBig text
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: black;">
</div>
```

Comment: This not add '...' at last line... and worse, cuts the text.

Comment: Yeah, usually the ellipsis requires white-space: nowrap so not sure how to do that with the text still wrapping. The answer with special display I don't believe is cross-platform...